# "The final argument passed to useEffect changed size between renders", except I don't think it does?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, axios, react-hooks

I don't think I've ever received this error before:

> The final argument passed to useEffect changed size between renders. The order and size of this array must remain constant.

I've done axios requests in `useEffect()` 100 times, using `useEffect()` in a similar manner to `componentDidMount()`, but this is the first time that I've used a reusable function with `async`/`await`, and resolved the data back to the `useEffect()`. Other people online are doing this exact same thing in their tutorials, but they never mentioned this error.

```
const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
        const data = async() => {
            const dataArr = await getPagList('tags', 1, 25)
            console.log("Data received: ", dataArr)
            if(dataArr.length > 0) {
                setTableData(dataArr)
            }
        }
        data()
    }, [])
```

I believe, it's complaining about the empty array I'm feeding `useEffect()` as the 2nd parameter. However, that empty array isn't changing... Right? I tried googling it, but the solutions I found for this error were what I'm already doing. None of the examples were using `async`/`await`.

I have also tried this, with no success:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        setData()
    }, [])

    const setData = () => {
        const data = async() => {
            const dataArr = await getPagList('tags', 1, 25)
            console.log("Data received: ", dataArr)
            if(dataArr.length > 0) {
                setTableData(dataArr)
            }
            // TODO Properly handle this data now that I'm getting it in. It's only 9 records though.
        }
        data()
    }
```

Am I not exiting the useEffect properly or something?
Anyway, thanks guys.

Comment: Are you sure that's the particular `useEffect()` call that React is complaining about?

Comment: You'll get this error if you actually give a different size array (the code you've quoted doesn't, all usages have a blank array) or if you have logic that changes the order of hook calls in your component and happens to swap two `useEffect` calls. Be sure **none** of the hook calls in your component are in branches, the type and order of the hooks you call has to be exactly the same for each render.

Comment: Other than that, we can't help you without a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Side note: You have a problem with your `setData` function: It doesn't handle potential rejections from `data`, and `data` doesn't ensure that it never rejects its promise. You need to either add a `catch` call to `data()` or use `try`/`catch` within `data` to catch all errors that may occur within it.

Comment: Patrick, you're right. I thought it was this one b/c it went away when I commented out the set state. But it's actually a child one that receives the data. I guess that's not something I thought could happen.

Answer (score 128):

If you have a

```
useEffect(() => {}, itemArray)
```

and you modify itemArray, you will get this error.  this is probably just a typo.  I did this when I had a list of items I was using from state.  It didn't catch it because it was an array.  You need [] around the itemArray.

```
useEffect(() => {}, [itemArray])
```

The real issue is that your dependency array changed size, not that you added another item to your array.  fix this typo and you should be fine.

Comment: Even if the dependency array is empty this warning is thrown. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: @AshTyson what do you mean?  useEffect(() => {}, []) does not throw an error.

Comment: No there are parts of our application it does throw this warning. Ofcourse we dont have a empty function as the first parameter

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean then.  show some code and i can take a look

Comment: Can't really post it all here because its proprietary. But here are some screenshots. React is very weird. https://ibb.co/xjJvv0x https://ibb.co/xJ4RpFQ  it threw 21 errors for the same line.

Comment: well, archiveId needs to be in the list to prevent the linting error.  I'm not sure without seeing the rest of the code what is going on.

Comment: That specific rule is disabled as you can see from the comment. This is the only useEffect in that file. And it throws this error multiple times. Thats why I say React doesn't handle/bubble errors very well.